# Calculating the magnitude of the force acting on a charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, charge, electromagnetic-induction

A charge of 40 µC moves with instantaneous velocity (v=5×104) j m/s through the uniform fields E=(6×104)(0.52 i +0.56 j +0.645 k) V/m and B=(1.7)(0.693 i +0.6 j +0.4 k) T. How do I calculate the magnitude of the force acting on the charge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ad the two forces $\vec{F_E}=\vec{E}*Q$ and $\vec{F_L}=Q*\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ and evaluate the absolute value

Answer (score 0):

By using the lorentz force

$\vec{F} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{V}×\vec{B})$

Comment: Why are the two similar answers down voted?

Comment: Clearly because someone needs to be banned.

Comment: I  up voted your answer to compensate